# Facelets Template Client doesnt load template

Tags: jsf

I have two Facelets Template client, First is the index.xhtml file. Index file load successfuly my template but when I try to load the second facelets client this can not load my template.

Template code

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
        <title>#{faceletsAuthorController.storeName}</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
            <h2>#{faceletsAuthorController.storeName}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="left">
                <h:form id="navForm">
                    <h:commandLink action="#{faceletsAuthorController.populateJavaRecipesAuthorList}">Java 7 Recipes</h:commandLink>
                    <br/>
                    <h:graphicImage id="javarecipes" style="width: 100px; height: 120px" library="image" name="java7recipes.png"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{faceletsAuthorController.populateJavaEERecipesAuthorList}">Java EE 7 Recipes</h:commandLink>
                    <br/>
                    <h:graphicImage id="javaeerecipes" style="width: 100px; height: 120px" library="image" name="javaee7recipes.png"/>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="left_content">
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom" style="position: absolute;width: 100%;bottom: 20px;">
            Written by Josh Juneau, Apress Author
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

index.xhtml Facelets Client

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Chapter 4 Examples</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="view/layout/custom_template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h1>Chapter 4 Example</h1>
                <p>
                    Facelets
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="view/example04_01a.xhtml">example04_01a.xhtml: Templates</a>
                </p>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

example04_01a.xhtml Second Faceletes Template (this one doesnt load the template)

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="view/layout/custom_template.xhtml">
            
            <ui:define name="top"></ui:define>
            <ui:define name="left"></ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="componentForm">
                    <h1>Author List for Java 7 Recipes</h1>
                    <p>
                        Below is the list of authors.  Click on the author's last name
                        for more information regarding the author.
                    </p>
                    <h:graphicImage id="javarecipes" style="width: 100px; height: 120px" library="image" name="java7recipes.png"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:dataTable id="authorTable" border="1" value="#{faceletsAuthorController.authorList}"
                                 var="author">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Java 7 Recipes Authors
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:commandLink id="authorName" action="#{faceletsAuthorController.displayAuthor(author.last)}"
                                           value="#{author.first} #{author.last}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="bottom"></ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I run the project I can see the index.xhtml file in the content or main zone perfectly loaded but when I clicked one element I can see the second page but without template loaded.

Thanks is advance any help.

Comment: Try making a [mcve]. Lots of irrelevant code in your pages. And check if the **relative** location of the template is correct. You usually reference templatese absolutely.

Comment: I tried using all my files in the same project root and doesn work. Atfer I tried using netbeans wizard but the same problem when I call the example04_01a.xhtml file it doesnt load the template

Comment: [mcve]... that is all can say...

Comment: What you are actually doing here is looking for the template in `view/view/layout/custom_template.xhtml`. This is why it's not showing up on the second page. There are relative paths and absolute ones - you want to use an absolute path in this case.
Also note that you should always protect your templates - put them inside `WEB-INF/`. There is no reason whatsoever to have them in the public tree. To use an absolute path referencing `WEB-INF` you can use something like `<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">` when you reference  your template.

Comment: There are probably previous questions discussing absolute/relative references with facelets... I didn't find a good one ... Care to do the honours @Kukeltje ? ;)

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg: although I still think it is in a way absolute vs relative template path related, OP states in a comment it is not. That is why I asked (again) for a [mcve]. I'm not going to put effort in a  answer unless op creates a [mcve] that can more easily read. But if you want to create an answer, be my guest. You'll at least get **my** upvote ;-)